# Mock all http requests of an android device

Tags: android, testing, mocking, httprequest, adb

I have got an Android app that uses some HTTP requests to different services on the internet. For testing I want to set up a WireMock instance that responses to this requests. The device is connected to the WireMock machine via USB. I do not want to change the URLs used in the APK to 'localhost' just for testing purposes.
Lets say my app uses those calls:

http://my-nice-web-api.com/some/path and https://an-even-better-web-api.com

I want this requests that are coming from the Android device to be routed to a port on my WireMock machine so I can read the requested URL and response with test data. How can I achieve this? This question is not so much about the WireMock logic but about the way of routing the calls.

Comment: Sounds like man-in-the-middle attack - especially for https not easy I'm worried

Comment: Yes you could call it like that. So I am also worried if this is possible due to security concerns. As you read I want to use it for tests and not for attacks :) I really want to avoid changing productive code in order to test.